# Create a tailored colorbar in matlab

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I have to create a map to show how far o how close some values are from a range and give them colors in consequence. Meanwhile, values that are within that range should have another different color.
For example: only the results that are within [-2 2] can be considered valid. For the other values, colors must show how far are from these limits (-3 lighter than -5, darker)
I've tried with *colorbar*  but I'm not able to set up a self-defined color scale.
Any idea??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a colormap for the range of values you have.
The colormap is N*3 matrix, defining the RGB values of each color.

See the example below, for a range -10:10 and valid values v1,v2:

```
v1=-3;  
v2=+3;  
a = -10:10;  
graylevels=[...  
   linspace(0,1,abs(-10-v1)+1) , ...
   ones(1, v2-v1-1) , ...
   linspace(1,0,abs(10-v2)+1)];  
c=repmat(graylevels , [3 1])';  
figure;  
imagesc(a);  
colormap(c);
```

Comment: Quite simple and quite easy to implement But in case a varies the scale varies too. How can I solve it?

Comment: You need to know which color to assign to which value. For example set the minimum & maximum values to black and the average value to white. Other option is to use percentiles of the data, which is more robust. Once you decide that, the mapping is easy: replace in the code above the values -10, 10, v1, v2 as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I just put together to demonstrate a simple means of creating your own lookup table and assigning values from it to the image that you're working with.  I'm assuming that your results are in a 2D array and I just used randomly assigned values, but the concept is the same.

I mention the potentila use of HSV as a coloring scheme.  Just note that, that requires you to have a m by n by 3 matrix.  The top layer is the H - hue, 2nd being the S - saturation and the 3rd being the V or value (light/dark).  Simply set the H and S to whatever values you want for the color and vary the V in a similar manner as shown below and you can get the varied light and dark color you want.

```
% This is just assuming a -10:10 range and randomly generating the values.
randmat = randi(20, 100);
randmat = randmat - 10;

% This should just be a black and white image.  Black is negative and white is positive.
figure, imshow(randmat) 

% Create your lookup table.  This will illustrate having a non-uniform
% acceptable range, for funsies.
vMin = -3;
vMax = 2;

% I'm adding 10 here to account for the negative values since matlab
% doesn't like the negative indicies...
map = zeros(1,20); % initialized
map(vMin+10:vMax+10) = 1; % This will give the light color you want.

%linspace just simply returns a linearly spaced vector between the values
%you give it.  The third term is just telling it how many values to return.
map(1:vMin+10) = linspace(0,1,length(map(1:vMin+10)));
map(vMax+10:end) = linspace(1,0,length(map(vMax+10:end))); 

% The idea here is to incriment through each position in your results and
% assign the appropriate colorvalue from the map for visualization.  You
% can certainly save it to a new matrix if you want to preserve the
% results!
for X = 1:size(randmat,1)
    for Y = 1:size(randmat,2)
        randmat(X,Y) = map(randmat(X,Y)+10);
    end
end

figure, imshow(randmat)
```